# get count of days against an amount with 1 percent amount daily in php

Tags: php, math, formula

I need to get the count of days for an Total amount which will be giving 1 percent of amount 'daily' from the total Amount.

```
Here is the formula if we knows the days:

$amount = 100;
$days = 100;

$daysCount = $amount/$days;
```

But I don't know the days count, I just wanted to get count of days. So how can I perform a formula to get days count when I don't know that an amount of 100, how many days it will take to distribute 1 percent of total amount daily?

```
$amount = 100;
$days = ?;

$daysCount = $amount/$days;
```

Comment: Where are the days held?  How do you need to count them?

Comment: I want to insert details in the table and before inserting I have to get days count as I mentioned. Actually the total amount should be any like it could be 100 OR 200 OR 300 etc. This amount submitted by the user and then i have to get the days count of total amount like if 100 is total amount and it should be distributed 1 percent daily. So the days count should be counted automatically.

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

```
$days = $amount/$daysCount
```

Example:

```
$amount = 100;
$days = 20;

$daysCount = 100/20;
//Value of $daysCount is 5.
```

According to this if you want to know $days

Then

```
$days = $amount / $daysCount;
//$days Value is 20.
```

In short you need to know 2 values out of 3 to be able to calculate the 3rd value.